# Is there a better way to join a repeatable text in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to combine a below code. Below code is working fine. I'm wondering if I can combine the below code to make it better and shorter because I have multiple set of dataframes where I need to append a seperate text to each set.

```
import pandas as pd

df_Gender = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [40, 30, 20], 'COl2': [50, 10, 5]})
 
name = ['Sam'] 
lis = []
for i in name:
    lis.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame({'i': lis})  #Creating a dataframe to append the name
df_Gender = df_Gender.join(df)  # joining name to the dataframe 

Output: 
Col1   COl2    name 
40     50      Sam
30     10      Nan
20     5       Nan
```

wrote a separate syntax for the text repetition in a column

```
name = repeat('Sam')
df_Gender['i'] = [next(name for lis in range(len(df_Gender))]

Expected Output: 
Col1   COl2    name 
40     50      Sam
30     10      Sam
20     5       Sam
```

Comment: `df_Gender['name'] = 'Sam'`

Comment: Thanks Nick for quick reply! Where exactly this needs to go to? After creating a dataframe?      After this - df = pd.DataFrame({'i': list})

Comment: Yeah, after you've created your `df_Gender` dataframe (which I presume has the `col1` and `col2` data in it, then just run that comment to fill a `name` column with `'Sam'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `df_Gender` is this

```
   Col1  COl2    i
0    40    50  Sam
1    30    10  NaN
2    20     5  NaN
```

you could use `.ffill()` to forward fill the null values

```
df_Gender['i'] = df_Gender['i'].ffill()
print(df_Gender)

   Col1  COl2    i
0    40    50  Sam
1    30    10  Sam
2    20     5  Sam
```